# how to populate only select keys from a schema object inside another schema in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, command-line-interface

I have 2 schemas:

```
var siteFeedbackSchema = new Schema({
    user: {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref: constants.DB_MODELS.USERS, required: true},
    comment: {type: String},
    __sv: {type: Number, default: SCHEMA_VERSION}
}, {strict: true, timestamps: { createdAt: 'created',  updatedAt: 'modified'}});

var usersSchema = new Schema({
    userName: {type: String, required: true},
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    __sv: {type: Number, default: SCHEMA_VERSION}
}, {strict: true, timestamps: { createdAt: 'created',  updatedAt: 'modified'}});
```

I populate the user key and when I do a GET on /sitefeedbackSchema and it returns doc:

```
{
"_id": "57850bd22e08cf206a3064e3"
"modified": "2016-07-12T15:25:06.652Z"
"created": "2016-07-12T15:25:06.652Z"
"comment": "good"
"user": {
    "_id": "5783cdcc20de829c5613a9a1"
    "modified": "2016-07-11T16:48:12.371Z"
    "created": "2016-07-11T16:48:12.371Z"
    "userName": "ramanr"
    "firstName": "rads"
    "lastName": "rrrr"
    "__v": 0
    "__sv": 1
}
"__v": 0
"__sv": 1
}
```

But, I only want the userName to be displayed from the user schema. Is there a way to select what keys we want?

```
{
"_id": "57850bd22e08cf206a3064e3"
"modified": "2016-07-12T15:25:06.652Z"
"created": "2016-07-12T15:25:06.652Z"
"comment": "good"
"user": {
    "userName": "ramanr"
      }
"__v": 0
"__sv": 1
}
```

Is there a cli to support this?

Comment: Can you use the [edit] link to show the part which calls the `.populate()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want a few specific fields returned for the populated documents? This can be accomplished by passing the usual field name syntax as the second argument to the populate method. I assume you use mongoose so you can use like

```
sitefeedback.find({})
   .populate('user', 'userName') // only return the userName
   .exec(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
         return res.status(400).send(err);
      }
      return res.status(200).send(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at projections. Basically MongoDB has been built to retrieve the full document each time but you can use the projection to oevercome this limitation : 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/